# Python Pet Class

Tags: python

I have a `class Pet()` and `main()` function as shown below. I get a syntax error, but it is not clear why.

```
class Pet(object):
    def __init__(self, name, animal_type, age):
        self.__name = name
        self.__animal_type = animal_type
        self.__age = age

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_type(self, animal_type):
        self.__animal_type = animal_type

    def set_age(self, age):
        self.__age = age

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_animal_type(self):
        return self.__animal_type

    def get__age(self):
        return self.__age

def main():

        name = input('What is the name of the pet: ')
        animal_type = input('What type of pet is it: ')
        age = int(input('How old is your pet: ')
        pets = Pet(name, animal_type, age)

        print('This will be added to the records.')
        print('Here is the data you entered: ')
        print('Pet Name: ', pets.get_name())
        print('Animal Type: ', pets.get_animal_type())
        print('Age: ', pets.get_age())

main()
```

I keep getting a syntax error for pets line

Comment: missing end parentheses on the `age = ` line?

Comment: I smell a homework problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 errors in your code, first, your init method needs to be written with double underscore, like this `__init__`, and secondly, you are missing a `)` on your age input line. If you put the code like this, it should work.

```
class Pet(object):
    def __init__(self, name, animal_type, age):
        self.__name = name
        self.__animal_type = animal_type
        self.__age = age

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_type(self, animal_type):
        self.__animal_type = animal_type

    def set_age(self, age):
        self.__age = age

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_animal_type(self):
        return self.__animal_type

    def get__age(self):
        return self.__age


def main():
    name = input('What is the name of the pet: ')
    animal_type = input('What type of pet is it: ')
    age = int(input('How old is your pet: '))
    pets = Pet(name, animal_type, age)

    print('This will be added to the records.')
    print('Here is the data you entered: ')
    print('Pet Name: ', pets.get_name())
    print('Animal Type: ', pets.get_animal_type())
    print('Age: ', pets.get__age())

main()
```

Comment: Thank you I found my mistake right after I posted it. Thank you though!!!

Comment: ang2010, if @Thrasd's post is a suitable answer, please vote it as such. Thrasd invested time to attempt to solve this problem and should be duly rewarded.